# Inserting a DIV after 2 paragraphs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to make it so that my posts insert a pullquote after 2 (or whatever number of) paragraphs. In the case of the website I'm working with, quotes are their own field, so I can't simply assign this to a blockquote tag. As such, I've cobbled together this solution:

```
    function insert_pullquote( $text ) {

    if ( is_singular('review') ) :

        $quote_text = get_template_part( 'pullquote' );
        $split_by = "\n\n";
        $insert_after = 2; //number of paragraphs

        // make array of paragraphs
        $paragraphs = explode( $split_by, $text);

        // if array elements are less than $insert_after set the insert point at the end
        $len = count( $paragraphs );
        if (  $len < $insert_after ) $insert_after = $len;

        // insert $ads_text into the array at the specified point
        array_splice( $paragraphs, $insert_after, 0, $quote_text );

        // loop through array and build string for output
        foreach( $paragraphs as $paragraph ) {
            $new_text .= $paragraph; 
        }

        return $new_text;

    endif;

    return $text;

}
    add_filter('the_content', 'insert_pullquote');
```

So, the good news is that it displays the pullquote as I want it ([see here](http://www.rpgfan.com/staging/review/100-rogues/)), but it doesn't do it after the 2 paragraphs. I'm using Wordpress' built-in function of get_template_part('pullquote');, which itself pulls from the field using echo(types_render_field( 'pullquote' )); If I just enter plain text, it works fine. What am I doing wrong? I'm a bit of a PHP kludge, so please bear with me on obvious mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `$new_text` is inside the loop.

You need

```
    $new_text="";    // declare out side loop
    foreach( $paragraphs as $paragraph ) {
        $new_text .= $paragraph; 
    }
    return $new_text;  // now is available here.
```

You could also use

```
$new_text =implode($paragraphs);  // to match your explode :-)
```

Comment: not sure if this will fix overall problem, but the fix I showed is needed anyhow.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a late reply but I only got back to working on this. Your fix works great, but it now prints the quote twice, once in the spot I need, and then after the body of the review. Is there a way to make it only print once?

Comment: Its hard to say. You are just inserting a string into an array of strings. I suggest do a `count( $paragraphs );` after the insert and make sure that its value has increased by 1 only, after the splice. Also in case I was not clear, don't use  `$new_text =implode($paragraphs);` if you have already used the `foreach` loop.